# How to get solve NoReverseMatch Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

I'm a novice to Python and Django. I am learning it from a tutorial but stuck in between. Already tried with some other StackOverflow solution but no luck. The following error I'm getting

Error: NoReverseMatch at /catalog/
Someone, please help me with the mistake that I have made.

url.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('book/<uuid:pk>/renew/', views.renew_book_librarian, name='renew-book-librarian'),
]
```

view.py

```
@permission_required('catalog.view_all_books')
def renew_book_librarian(request, pk):
    """View function for renewing a specific BookInstance by librarian."""
    book_instance = get_object_or_404(BookInstance, pk=pk)

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        book_renewal_form = RenewBookForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if book_renewal_form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
            book_instance.due_back = book_renewal_form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']
            book_instance.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-borrowed'))

    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:
        proposed_renewal_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
        book_renewal_form = RenewBookForm(initial={'renewal_date': proposed_renewal_date})

    context = {
        'form': book_renewal_form,
        'book_instance': book_instance,
    }

    return render(request, 'catalog/book_renew_librarian.html', context)
```

model.py

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library).
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
            return True
        return False

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('d', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS, blank=True, default='d', help_text='Book availability')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["due_back"]
        permissions = (("view_all_books", "View all books"),)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        # return '%s (%s)' % (self.id,self.book.title)
        # return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.id, self.book.title)
        return self.book.title
```

forms.py

```
class RenewBookForm(forms.Form):
    renewal_date = forms.DateField(help_text="Enter a date between now and 4 weeks (default 3).")

    def clean_renewal_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['renewal_date']

        # Check if a date is not in the past.
        if data < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - renewal in past'))

        # Check if a date is in the allowed range (+4 weeks from today).
        if data > datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=4):
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - renewal more than 4 weeks ahead'))

        # Remember to always return the cleaned data.
        return data
```

book_renew_librarian.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Renew: {{ book_instance.book.title }}</h1>
  <p>Borrower: {{ book_instance.borrower }}</p>
  <p>Book ID: {{ book_instance.id }}</p>
  <p {% if book_instance.is_overdue %} class="text-danger"{% endif %}>Due date: {{ book_instance.due_back }}</p>

  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

base_generic.html

```
{% if perms.catalog.view_all_books %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' book_instance.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /catalog/mybooks/          Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog\\/book\\/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\\/renew\\/$']

Comment: Error during template rendering:  showing error in template like {% if perms.catalog.view_all_books %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' book_instance.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}

Comment: The first error is saying that the argument you're passing (book_instance.id) is blank. My guess is in your view, you're not passing book_instance as context. It would look something like this: `return render(request, 'base_generic.html', context={'book_instance': your_book_instance_goes_here})`. If you don't do this, your template doesn't have any idea what book_instance is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181436/discussion-between-keshavgarg-and-phplover).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding a for loop to the  book_renew_librarian template

```
{% block content %}

{% for bookinst in bookinstance_list %}


  <h1>Renew: {{ book_instance.book.title }}</h1>- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  
  <p>Borrower: {{ book_instance.borrower }}</p>- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  
  <p{% if book_instance.is_overdue %} class="text-danger"{% endif %}>Due date: {{ book_instance.due_back }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```